# navbars shifted when compatibility view toggled

Tags: css, position, compatibility, mode, shift

When I toggle IE9's Compatibility VIEW on/off, my navbar shifts positions:

---

When Compatibility View: **ON:**

```
navbar is centred fine. :)
```

When Compatibility View: **OFF:**

```
navbar is shifted to the right slightly. :(
```

---

**NOTE:** I could NOT attach a screenshot due to certain site restrictions. :(

---

Obviously I would like to correct this, but cannot; thus, why I am posting here. :)

**My CSS file looks as follows:**

```
/*background image for outside area*/
#outside {
    background-image:url('/images/body_bg.gif');
}

/*style for main area*/
#main {
    font:16px "Trebuchet MS", arial, verdana, serif, monospace;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1020px;
    border:5px outset darkgrey;
    background-color:white;
}

/*background image*/
#bg {
    background-image:url('/images/content_bg.gif');
}

/*horizontal list item widths*/
ul.two li{width:50%;}
ul.four li{width:25%;}
ul.five li{width:20%;}

/*submenu list item widths*/
ul.sfour li a{width:25em;} /*alternate value = 19.1em*/
ul.sfive li a{width:18.5em;} /*alternate value = 15.3em*/

/*top navigation bar*/
#topnav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#topnav li {
    float:left;
}

#topnav li a {
    background-color:#606060;
    color:white;
    display:block;
    font-size:large;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    padding-top:4px;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#topnav li a:active {
    color:yellow;
}

#topnav li a:hover {
    background-color:#888888;
}

/*topnav submenus*/
#topnav li ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}

#topnav li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

#topnav li:hover li {
    float:none;
}

#topnav li:hover a {
    background-color:#888888;
}

#topnav li:hover li a {
    display:block;
    font-size:small;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-variant:normal;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#topnav li:hover li a:hover {
    background-color:#B0B0B0
}

/*page title*/
h1 {
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    color:gray;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:90%;
}

/*content*/
#content {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:90%;
}
```

**My _Layout.cshtml file is as follows:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>C4DP - @Page.Title</title>
        <link href="@Href("~/Styles/Style.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/functions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/sorttable.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="outside">
        <div id="main">
            <img src="/images/title_c4dp.gif" alt="C4DP" width="100%"/>
            <div id="bg">
                <div id="topnav">@RenderPage("~/navbar_Top.cshtml")</div>
                <h1>@Page.Title</h1>
                <div id="content">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
                <div id="bottomnav">@RenderPage("~/navbar_Bottom.cshtml")</div>
            </div>
            <p id="copyright">&copy; 2012 C4DP. All rights reserved.</p>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The navbar file looks as follows:

```
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
    if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("admin")) {
        <ul class="four">
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/News.cshtml")">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stats</a>
                <ul class="sfour">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Earnings.cshtml")">Earnings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/SessionAverage.cshtml")">Session Average</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Ranking.cshtml")">Ranking</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
                <ul class="sfour">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/UserProfile.cshtml")">Personal Info.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/ChangePassword.cshtml")">Change Password</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Logout.cshtml")">Logout</a></li>
        </ul> 
    } else { //logged in as administrator
        <ul  class="five">
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/News.cshtml")">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Stats</a>
                <ul class="sfive">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Earnings.cshtml")">Earnings</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/SessionAverage.cshtml")">Session Average</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Ranking.cshtml")">Ranking</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin</a>
                <ul class="sfive">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Admin/Cardrooms.cshtml")">Cardrooms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Events.cshtml")">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Members.cshtml")">Members</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
                <ul class="sfive">
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/UserProfile.cshtml")">Personal Info.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/ChangePassword.cshtml")">Change Password</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Logout.cshtml")">Logout</a></li>
        </ul> 
    }
} else {
    // nav bar when NOT logged in
    <ul class="four">
        <li><a href="@Href("~/Default.cshtml")">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Href("~/Rules.cshtml")">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/Login.cshtml")">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="@Href("~/Account/RequestMembership.cshtml")">Request Membership</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Please help!

Comment: You specify if your site supports compatibility mode or not. There shouldn't be a context where you are required to support both like you are describing.

Comment: sorry, i guess i meant IE's Compatibility VIEW; when i toggle that, my navbars are all over the place. :(

Comment: I misread your issue. It works when in compatibility view, but not when using standard IE7, IE8 and IE9 views. Which rendering mode are you looking at currently?

Comment: how can i tell? <i'm kinda new to all this> :)

Comment: JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2auzn/1/ what is the exact problem you are having? The nav looks fine...

Comment: It turns out that my navbar needed the {display:inline;} and {padding:0;} attributes added to it to make it work.

Not being a real guru at this stuff, I assume the INLINE attribute prevented it from being "pushed over" by its neighbouring element, and that the PADDING:0; attribute ensured that the navbar fit properly in its parent element.

If a "real guru" (someone with more experience than me) could confirm my assumption, that would be bonus.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my navbar needed the `{display:inline;} and {padding:0;}` attributes added to it to make it work.

Not being a real guru at this stuff, I assume the `INLINE` attribute prevented it from being "pushed over" by its neighbouring element, and that the `PADDING:0;` attribute ensured that the navbar fit properly in its parent element.

If a "real guru" (someone with more experience than me) could confirm my assumption, that would be much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.